# レーベンシュタイン距離は、「置換に割り振るコストの値」によって結果が異なる？

Tags: アルゴリズム

**「kitten」「sitting」、2単語間のレーベンシュタイン距離は、設定によって「3」だったり「5」だったりするのでしょうか？**
・「レーベンシュタイン距離」はあくまでも考え方であって、正式な公式は存在しない？
・あるいは、公式はあるけれども、そこへ割り振るコストは自由に設定可能ということでしょうか？
・一般的には置換コストは「1」「2」、何れなのでしょうか？

> 上の変形では挿入・削除・置換のそれぞれのコストを1に設定したが、これらのコストには別々の値を割り振る事も可能である

https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%83%99%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A5%E3%82%BF%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E8%B7%9D%E9%9B%A2

Comment: 日本語版Wikipediaの記述は間違っていることが多いので、変だと思ったら英語版を見たほうがいいです。もっともWiki自体信頼できるわけではないので、原典を当たるのが一番ですが。それはさて置き、Wikiの「ノート」を見ると特定の実装に合わせて記事を修正したことがわかります。実装に合わせて仕様を変えるのはダメでしょう。

Comment: こう書いた後で特定の実装の話をするのはアレですが、Python-Levenshteinで`distance("kitten", "sitting")`は置換、置換、挿入の操作で距離は3になりました。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。Wikiに「ノート」欄なんてあったのですね、初めて知りました。また、Wiki英語版を見るという発想はなかったので覗いてみたのですが、日本版とは結構異なっていたの（より詳しそう）で驚きました

Comment: Python-Levenshtein情報ありがとうございます。ネットで見つけたJavaScriptのサンプルを試してみたところ、同じく3となりました

Answer (score 0, accepted):

まず置換のコストについて

レーベンシュタイン距離の定義は、

> 具体的には、1文字の挿入・削除・置換によって、一方の文字列をもう一方の文字列に変形するのに必要な手順の最小回数として定義される

ですので、置換操作が許されるならばコストは1、置換操作が許されない場合はそれを削除・挿入で置き換えてコストは2となります。
また手順の「最小」回数を求めるので、置換操作が許されるならば、それを削除・挿入で置き換えてコストを2とすることはできません。

従って、置換操作を許すか否かでレーベンシュタイン距離が変わることになります。

参考:
名前の元となった論文は[こちら](https://gitlab.doc.ic.ac.uk/wm613/inidividual-project/raw/4fbe43f863b229b50ca13bf5f59eb029ad71f6b6/reading/litreview/levenshtein66.pdf)。

Comment: 論文読みましたか？元の論文は「挿入・削除・反転の訂正が可能な二進符号」がタイトルです。通信経路上でビットが欠落、誤検出、または反転した時に訂正可能なコードの考案だったのですね。挿入削除のみのケースを証明し、次に反転を含めた証明に拡張しています。最後に無限のビット列に適用した場合の考察で終わっています。単語への適用については挿入削除の証明の章にて唯一脚注に考察がありますけれど、長さの違う単語についてはこの補題は常になりたつとは限らないとあります。この論文から単語間の距離を定義するまでにはだいぶ飛躍があります。

Answer (score 1):

通常、自然言語処理や生物情報科学の範囲で単に[「レーベンシュタイン距離」](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)と言った場合、1 回の編集として 1 文字の挿入・削除・置換が許されていて、それぞれにかかるコストが 1 であるような[編集距離](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance)のことを言います。この定義のもとでは "kitten" と "sitting" のレーベンシュタイン距離は 3 になります。

ただし上で述べた「コスト」を挿入・削除・置換のそれぞれについて個別に設定できるように一般化することもでき、重み付きレーベンシュタイン距離と呼ばれています。また編集操作を制限したり追加したりするなどして、広義の[「編集距離」](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance)として一般化することもできます。日本語版 Wikipedia の当該の記述はこのことに対応しようとしたのかもしれません。